# Streaming a virtual terminal without video

Tags: html, streaming, xtermjs

If I want to live broadcast some work on a text editor embedded in a virtual terminal on my personnal computer, I can stream on the web a video of the window containing it.

But since information consists mainly in a bunch of characters, possibly with some colors and formating, I think that video is a waste of ressources, bandwidth and technology speaking.

**What would you recommend for this, and is there some server implementing the solution somewhere ?**

The requirements are :

- the stream must be almost real time (at least 1 update per second and no more than 1 second delay)
- audience can access the stream with only a web browser (no additional software on their side), read-only (no interaction with the stream or with my terminal)
- features from say `xterm` or `urxvt` be supported
- all necessary software (both streamer client side and potential server side) are open source

Comments on technical advantages of such tool compared to video streaming are welcome.

Comment: If you have access to the first terminal (better its IO stream) the easiest way to achieve a readonly terminal clone is to spawn an xterm.js instance and reroute the original IO chunks coming from the OS to also show up on the cloned terminal instance.The important bit is to only deal with chunks from the OS and not to allow input from the clones, otherwise they have write access.

Comment: @jerch thanks I was indeed thinking at something of the sort, but I do not know how to do this in practice

Comment: You could use tmux for the IO duping: create a new session in the main terminal `tmux new-session -s yourSessionName`, then attach a second readonly terminal (can be xterm.js) to that session with `tmux attach-session -t yourSessionName -r`.

Comment: Ok so tmux might help in the process. But there remains many gaps that I am unable to fill. Not sure how xterm.js provides me a terminal that I can attach to a tmux session, even less if my terminal is only on a client machine and the xterm.js is on a server.

Comment: You call tmux in xterm.js, it connects to the other session (not xterm.js directly). If your original terminal (where you created the tmux session) runs locally, but the the pty of term.js on the server - well then you need to hook up some way to forward the session data to the server (e.g. ssh tunnel or any other transport).

Answer (score 1):

I finally took the time to implement a complete solution, using socket.io within a simple NodeJS server for broadcasting.

On the client side, serve a simple HTML with an Xterm.js terminal

```html
<script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
<script src="xterm/xterm.js"></script>
...
<div class="terminal" id="terminal"></div>
```

and script the synchronization along the lines of

```js
var socket = io();
term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));
var updateTerminal = socket.on("updateTerminal", function(data) {
    term.write(data);
});
```

Now the `data` that can be passed to `term.write` of Xterm.js can be raw terminal data. Several UNIX utilities can monitor such raw data from a terminal, for instance tmux as proposed by jerch in the comments, or script.

To pass these data to the server for broadcasting, the easiest way is to use a named pipe; so on the server side

```sh
mkfifo server_pipe
script -f server_pipe
```

(the terminal issuing that last command will be the one broadcasting; if one does not have physical access to the server, one can use an additional pipe and a tunneling connection

```sh
mkfifo local_pipe
cat local_pipe | ssh <server> 'cat > path/to/server_pipe'&
script -f local_pipe
```

)

Finally, the NodeJS server must be listening to the named pipe and broadcast any new data

```js
/* create server */
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    ...
});

/* open named pipe for reading */
const fs = require('fs');
const fd = fs.openSync("path/to/server_pipe", 'r+')
const termStream = fs.createReadStream(null, {fd});
termStream.setEncoding('utf8');

/* broadcast any new data with socket.io */
const iolib = require("socket.io");
io = iolib(server);
termStream.on('data', function(data) {
    io.emit("updateTerminal", data)
});
```

---

All this mechanism is implemented in my software [Remote lecture](https://gitlab.com/1a7r0ch3/remote-lecture).

---

As for the comparison with video broadcast, I did not take the time to actually quantify the difference, but for equivalent resolution and latency, the above mechanism should use much less network and computing resources than capturing a graphic terminal output and sharing it with video.